# failed to read Dockerfile MacOS GoLang; Trying to create an image

Tags: bash, docker, macos, go, dockerfile

I keep running into that error on the last line and have tried putting the dockerfile in the tmp folder but still get the same error; I even tried upper casing and lowercasing the docker file name, it didn't resolve the issue.

my file path is `Users/maheenk/Desktop/infra`

my docker file :

```sh
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

#using latest version
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /app

#Download necessary Go modules
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

#copies source code onto image
COPY *.go ./

#static application in rootfilesystem
RUN docker build -t internhw:latest -f .Dockerfile .

EXPOSE 8080

#command to execute when image is used to start a container
CMD [ "internhw"]
```

the command I run in terminal:

```sh
docker build -t internhw:latest -f .Dockerfile .
```

what the output is in terminal:

```
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from .Dockerfile                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                   0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount200403056/.Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Output of command in terminal: `ls -al`

```
total 160
drwxrwxr-x@   9 maheenk  staff    288 Apr 24 11:42 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 110 maheenk  staff   3520 Apr 23 17:24 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 maheenk  staff   6148 Apr 24 11:42 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   14 maheenk  staff    448 Apr 24 11:00 .git
-rw-r--r--@   1 maheenk  staff    523 Apr 24 10:54 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 maheenk  staff    669 Apr 23 16:26 go.mod
-rw-r--r--    1 maheenk  staff  56262 Apr 23 16:26 go.sum
-rw-r--r--    1 maheenk  staff   2126 Apr 23 16:09 main.go
```

I added a .Dockerfile to the folder(basically a copy of the dockerfile that i renamed by putting a period in front of)

````
drwxrwxr-x@   9 maheenk  staff    288 Apr 24 13:03 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 111 maheenk  staff   3552 Apr 24 12:43 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 maheenk  staff   6148 Apr 24 13:03 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@   1 maheenk  staff    513 Apr 24 13:06 .Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x   14 maheenk  staff    448 Apr 24 13:00 .git
-rw-r--r--@   1 maheenk  staff    523 Apr 24 10:54 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 maheenk  staff    669 Apr 23 16:26 go.mod
-rw-r--r--    1 maheenk  staff  56262 Apr 23 16:26 go.sum
-rw-r--r--    1 maheenk  staff   2126 Apr 23 16:09 main.go```
````

**UPDATED VERSION**:

redid the run line in docker as suggested

````
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:latest


WORKDIR /app

# Download necessary Go modules
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

#copies source code onto image
COPY *.go ./

#static application in rootfilesystem
RUN build -t internhw:latest .Dockerfile .


EXPOSE 8080

#command to execute when image is used to start a container
CMD [ "internhw" ] ```
````

when i run in terminal  `docker build -t internhw:latest .Dockerfile .`

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Comment: Please include the output of `ls -al` in your question, from the same directory where you run the `docker build` command.

Comment: You can't (and don't need to) `RUN docker` in the Dockerfile.  Since `Dockerfile` is the standard name, you don't need the `docker build -f` option either; you are trying to point it at a different file `.Dockerfile` (with a leading `.`) that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It does make little sense to do a `docker build` inside a Dockerfile which is itself... 'docker built'.

If you need to add resources to an existing image, you can use COPY or ADD inside your `Dockerfile`.

If you need to compile something and put the result in an existing image, you can use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).